# How to install MSV (XML validator)

Tags: xml, validation, relaxng

I am looking for a free good XML validator for Relax NG, particularly. I read about MSV and would like to use it. Google brought me to [this website](https://msv.java.net/). However, when I clicked 'download', I was directed to a files repository. I couldn't see any executable installer. I wonder whether I landed on the right site.

I am using Windows 8. How can I install MSV?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for a command line tool, you probably need a `.jar` file. I found an older version at http://java.net/downloads/msv/releases/ (via https://www.philipp-wagner.com/blog/2012/04/using-the-the-sunoracle-multi-schema-xml-validator-msv/ ).

That said, it doesn't seem like MSV is used much. I usually hear more about [Jing](http://www.thaiopensource.com/relaxng/jing.html) and [RNV](http://www.davidashen.net/rnv.html).